# How to debounce a touch (or left mouse click) in Windows?

Tags: windows-8.1, touchscreen, mouse-click

I have a tablet with defective touchscreen. It often treat a single tap as double tap. As a result, it frequently zoom in and out. I have tried Touch Calibration and it did not help.

I wonder if there is a way to modify the behavior such that 2 clicks in close succession (e.g. less than 0.1s) is treated as 1.

Comment: Have you tried changing the double-click speed in Mouse properties via the Control Panel?

Comment: Yes, and it only makes it easier to double click.

Comment: Even if you change it to the Fastest setting?

Comment: Fastest setting is still humanly possible. The issue is phantom clicks caused by touchscreen happens in very very short time.

Comment: In that case I doubt you'll find any way to override defective hardware behaviour using software. Still, don't take my word for it and wait and see if someone can come up with a viable workaround or solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution! There is an AutoHotKey script that can debounce a mouse button:

http://jslover.secsrv.net/AutoHotkey/Scripts/Buggy-Mouse

My problem is 90% gone after running the script. And I can turn it on/off if needed.

On the other hand, I also found more information about the double click. Under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse

http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/341/

There are 3 parameters. DoubleClick Speed, Height and Width. I can make the values unreasonably small to make it difficult to double click. But that would also mean it is impossible to pull off double click again. But the script above is much better as it is setting up a minimum double click interval (debounce).

Edit: I should mention that the above method does not work inside Internet Explorer. Instead, I found the solution here

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie10-windows_rt/how-do-you-disable-double-tap-on-the-screen/023b21b5-e516-4922-a5ee-c8937a17895c

Essentially, loading a local .css file:

```
body {
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation !important;
}
```